# Convert array to object using values like keys

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a project in Typescript in which I am trying to create a function that converts an array into an object using the first values as keys of the object.

This is my array:

```
let testArr = ["id", "ser", "add", "1", "asd", "82.255", "2", "ert", "82.119", "3", "pol", "82.250"];
```

This is what I need:

```
let newArr = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "ser": "asd",
    "add": "82.255"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "ser": "ert",
    "add": "82.119"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "ser": "pol",
    "add": "82.250"
  }
]
```

In result I store the data of the array that I want to use as keys of the object:

```
let chunk = 3;

let result = testArr.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => { 
    const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/chunk)

    if(!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
        resultArray[chunkIndex] = [] // start a new chunk
    }

    resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)

    return resultArray
}, [])
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use that data as keys of the object and I would like to know how to convert the result variable into a generic function for any array and any number.

Comment: Extract the property names, `for ( ...; ...; i += <properties.length>) { ... }` -> done

Comment: @Andreas I just updated the question with what I have

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the testArr array using forEach and check the index. if it's a multiple of 3 you can assign an object with the values and push that object to the new array.

For your case, i've modified the answer to a generic case where you can pass the starting index of the values in the original array

```js
let testArr = ["id", "ser", "add", "1", "asd", "82.255", "2", "ert", "82.119", "3", "pol", "82.250"];

const arr = [];

function genericArrayFormatter(checkIdx){
  testArr.forEach((val, idx) => {
    if (idx > checkIdx - 1 && idx % checkIdx === 0){
      const obj = {};
      let i = 0;
      let index = idx;
      while (checkIdx > i){
        obj[testArr[i++]] = testArr[index++];
      }
      arr.push(obj);
    }
  });
}

genericArrayFormatter(3);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: How can I transform that function into a generic function using reduce? I don't really understand how it works now

Comment: @print Then start to learn. Just copy&pasting stuff from the internet doesn't teach you anything.

Comment: @print i've added a generic solution. hope this helps you

Comment: @Andreas Everything I learn or watch on the internet I try to understand it and adapt it to the best way I understand it, but I am studying and I do not have enough experience to be agile in many things, I am sorry if my question has bothered you but I just want to learn programming in the best possible way

Comment: Then start by trying to understand what actually happens in Rans answer (although the [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69270311/1) would have been a better start for a beginner). Start with `.forEach()`, try to understand the `if` condition, learn how the debugger in your browser works and use it to step through the loop (or use pen and paper), ...